# Transform nested JSON in data factory to sql

Tags: azure-data-factory

New to data factory. I have a json file that needs to manipulate but I can't figure out how to go about it. The file has a generic "name" property but it should have the value as the key name. How can I get it so that I can get the value as key?
So far been getting Complex JSON errors. This json is coming from file store.

```
[
    {
        "Version": "1.1",
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocumentState": "Correct",
                "DocumentData": {
                    "Name": "Name1",
                    "$type": "Document",
                    "Fields": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Form",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Birthday Form"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Date",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "12/1/1999"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "FirstName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "John"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "FirstName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Smith"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Version": "1.1",
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocumentState": "Correct",
                "DocumentData": {
                    "Name": "Name2",
                    "$type": "Document",
                    "Fields": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Form",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Entry Form"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Date",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "4/3/2010"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "FirstName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Jane"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "LastName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Doe"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected output

```
DocumentData: [
{
  "Form":"Birthday Form",
  "Date": "12/1/1999",
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Smith"
},
{
  "Form":"Entry Form",
  "Date": "4/3/2010",
  "FirstName": "Jane",
  "LastName": "Doe"
}
]
```

Comment: Please share expected output.

Comment: @AbhishekKhandave-MT please see the updated output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jaimers,

I was able to achieve it by making use of the **Data Flow Activity**

The below is the complete [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview)

[image]

**1) Source1**

This step involves getting the data from source. You will have to configure the Source dataset.

The only change I had done in the source was to Convert Fields.Name,Field.Type,Field.Value as string[] (From string).

This was required to make/create key value pair of the fields in the Subsequent steps.

[image]

2. **Flatten1**
   I had made use of Flatten at the Document level.

And got the values of DocumentData.DocumentName and DocumentData.Fields

**Note :** If you don't want DocumentData.DocumentName - You can safely ignore it.

[image]

**4) DerivedColumn1**

This is actual step where I convert name:key1 key:value1 to key1:value1.

To do that I had made use of the below expression :

```
keyValues(Fields.Name,Fields.Value)
```

**Note:** Keyvalues() function expects 2 array arguments. Hence, in the first step we had changed the type of Fields.Name and Fields.Value to array.

[image]

**4) Select**

Just to select the columns that need to be sent as an output

[image]

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned SQL in your title so if you have access to a SQL database, eg Azure SQL DB, then it is quite capable with manipulating JSON, eg using the `OPENJSON` and `FOR JSON PATH` methods.  A simple example:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '[
    {
        "Version": "1.1",
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocumentState": "Correct",
                "DocumentData": {
                    "Name": "Name1",
                    "$type": "Document",
                    "Fields": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Form",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Birthday Form"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Date",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "12/1/1999"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "FirstName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "John"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "FirstName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Smith"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Version": "1.1",
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocumentState": "Correct",
                "DocumentData": {
                    "Name": "Name2",
                    "$type": "Document",
                    "Fields": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Form",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Entry Form"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Date",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "4/3/2010"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "FirstName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Jane"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "LastName",
                            "$type": "Text",
                            "Value": "Doe"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]'

-- Restructure the JSON and add a root
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @json )
WITH
(
    Form        VARCHAR(50) '$.Documents[0].DocumentData.Fields[0].Value',
    [Date]      DATE '$.Documents[0].DocumentData.Fields[1].Value',
    FirstName   VARCHAR(50) '$.Documents[0].DocumentData.Fields[2].Value',
    LastName    VARCHAR(50) '$.Documents[0].DocumentData.Fields[3].Value'
)
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('DocumentData');
```

My results:

[image: Results]

NB I've used the ROOT clause to add a root to the JSON document.  You could make the `@json` a stored proc parameter and use a Stored Proc task from the pipeline.